# How to get USB Game controller to work on rooted Xperia Z Tablet

Tags: usb, game-controllers

I have a USB game controller I always use in my rooted Tecno Phantom Pad running Android 4.2.1 which works fine but can't get it to work on my rooted Sony Xperia Z Tablet running Android 5.1.1.

I tried to snoop the USB controller device info from my Xperia Z Tablet and got this.

[image: result]

This means that my device can detect the USB Game controller but yet nothing happens. I also ran this test via a powered USB Hub.

How can I get this to work?